# Background image path not working in css file using gulp js

Tags: javascript, css, gulp, gulp-concat

I am working on a project where I am concatenating all files, minifying and renaming by gulp.

When I write an image path as a background image in my main css file it is not working in the minified file. Actually I am unable to set the image path as it is getting compiled in my minified file which is in another directory.

My File route flow

```
    assets -->
          --css
             --main.css
          --img

    dist -->
           --css
            --all-styles-min.css

   gulpfile.js
```

I have put an image file inside the assets/img folder and am calling that file inside my main.css

My `gulp.js`

```
return gulp.src([
      'assets/css/animate.min.css',
       'assets/css/bootstrap.css',
        'assets/css/vendor/bootstrap-select.min.css',
        'assets/css/vendor/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css',
         'assets/css/vendor/jquery.timepicker.css',
         'assets/css/default.css',
          'assets/css/main.css',
          'assets/css/responsive.css',
       ])
        .pipe(concat('all_styles.css'))
        .pipe(cleanCSS({compatibility: 'ie8'}))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
         browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
         cascade: false
       }))
       .pipe(rename('all_styles.min.css'))
       .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
});
```

and in my `main.css`

```
.black-bg{
    background:url('../img/black-multiply-bg.png') 0 0 repeat;
}
```

I am seeing this console error for image file not found

```
http://localhost/projects/P-09-sakha/html/dist/css/assets/img/black-multiply-bg.png 404 (Not Found)
```

The source is showing the dist folder. I have also checked with [gulp-css-url-adjuster](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-css-url-adjuster) but still am unable to make it work.

Comment: You might want to add how you configured the gulp-css-url-adjuster in order to get better feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue of css-url-adjuster today while working for another project.

What I found the format of the coding was not correct for me before. So I am sharing in hope someone may find helpful from this.

For this I have used 4 Gulp plugins.
1. gulp-clean-css
2. gulp-cssmin
3. gulp-rename
4. gulp-css-url-adjuster

and the code is:

```
gulp.task('css', function(){
return gulp.src([
 '../html/assets/css/main.css',
  ])

/**
 *
 * Note
 * To Use minify and fixing the image path, you have
 * to use both gulp-clean-css & gulp-cssmin & gulp-css-url-adjuster
 * and the format must follow the below code
 * else you will get error
 */

.pipe(concat('apps.css'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('../html/assets/css'))
.pipe(cleanCSS({compatibility: 'ie8'}))
.pipe(urlAdjuster({
       prepend: '../img/',
      }))
.pipe(cssmin())
.pipe(rename({suffix:'.min'})) 
.pipe(gulp.dest('../html/assets/css'))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I only got some experience with Grunt, not Gulp unfortunately.
But since I did run into something similar in the past, I'll tell you what I did.

I used the `replace` functionality to apply a regex replacing the "wrong" urls for the right ones.

In my case: `replace: [{files: 'index.html', regex: /\.\.\/dist\/css/g, replacement: 'css'}]`, replacing all `../dist/css` for `css` in the `index.html` file. For example, `<link href="../dist/css/style.css" />` will become `<link href="css/style.css" />`.

I'm sure Gulp has something similar.

Comment: The gulp-css-url-adjuster plugin he mentions actually seems to be the perfect solution (it does what you're talking about).  Probably not configuring it properly.

Comment: Yes I am unable to configure. Actually I am stuck at prepend: '/image_directory/',  I am writing my image directory as 'assets/img', Still it is not working. I am really confused can anyone please help me to sort it out. Thanks in advance